# JQuery UI Datepicker with Time Plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, drupal, uidatepicker

I have the following script to generate a date/time picker for my Drupal "Authored On:" field.

```
$(function() {$( "#edit-date" ).datetimepicker({
showButtonPanel: true, 
dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd", 
showSecond: true, 
timeFormat: "hh:mm:ss"
});
});
```

This generates almost the proper format of the date time: 2010-12-22 00:15:56 except in drupal, they seem to subtract the timezone:2010-12-22 00:15:56 **-0700**

How would I go about adding the -0700 to the end of the string onselect?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the timepicker plugin is being used, the onselect won't return the correct date/time.

I ended up changing the source of the timepicker plugin to add "-0700" onchange...